# manipulating two-dimensional arrays of String

Tags: java

this is an array of process, that have inforamtion like, number of proces, name and sex

```
private String process[][] = {
            {"0001", "Maria Gomes", "Feminino"},
            {"0002", "José Santos", "Masculino"},
            {"0003", "João Oliveira", "Masculino"}};
```

and I have doubt here, to get the next new number of process, in array is 0003, and the next is 0004

```
public String getNewNextNumberOfProcess() {//
        for (int i = 0; i < process.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < process[i].length; j++) {
                return process[i][j];
            }
        }
        return "-1";
    }
```

and I have doubt here, in create process

```
public boolean createProcess(String number_process, String name, String sex) {
          for (int i = 0; i < process.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < process[i].length; j++) {
                 //add number of process
                 process[i][0] += number_process;
                 //add name
                 process[i][1] += name;
                 //add sex 
                 process[i][2] += sex;
                 return true;
               }
            }            
      return false;
 }
```

and I have doubt here, in delete process

```
public boolean deleteProcess(String numberProcess) {
        for (int i = 0; i < process.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < process[i].length; j++) {
                //if number of process is the same in array of process
                if(numberProcess.equals(process[i][j])){
                 //delete all information associated with number of process
                 process[i][j] -= process[i][0];
                 //return true
                  return true;
                }
               }
            }       
      return false;
 }
```

Comment: You have a lot of "doubts" but what's the problem?

Comment: getNewNextNumberOfProcess function does not get any parameter. it always gives process[0][0]. even other functions. you always do someting on [0][0]

Comment: I think you're using Strings where you shouldn't use them.

Comment: I think you're using arrays where you shouldn't use them.

Comment: I doubt I can answer this without knowing what the actual question is.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String getNewNextNumberOfProcess() {//
    for (int i = 0; i < process.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < process[i].length; j++) {
            return process[i][j];
        }
    }
    return "-1";
}
```

Will always return process[0][0] during the first iteration of the j for loop inside the i for loop.

May I suggest using a different data structure. What if you used a Map with the process as the key and an array with the name and sex as the value?

Here is some more information on Maps.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Comment: What made you pick `Dictionary` over `Map`, given that that javadoc page explicitly says `Dictionary` is obsolete?

Comment: @dcshol Good catch. I have been working in C# lately and had forgotten a Map was the better choice in Java.

Comment: @dcshol, in this time I can´t use the collections because this I'm doing a java course for beginners and this time I only use the basic commands

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better if you create a Process class and implement it like this:

```html
        private Map<Integer, Process> processes = new HashMap<Integer, Process>;

        public class Process
        {
            public int processId;
            public string processName;
            public string processSex;
        }

        public void AddProcess(Process process)
        {
            if (processes.get(process.processId) == null)
            {
                processes.put(process.processId, process);
            }
        }

        public void DeleteProcess(Process process)
        {
            if (processes.get(process.processId) != null)
            {
                processes.remove(process.processId);
            }
        }
```

Comment: in this time I can´t use the collections because this I'm doing a java course for beginners and this time I only use the basic commands

Comment: I think at least create a Process class and use an array of Process. Even you are addressing to beginners they have to learn thinking basing on Object Oriented concept.